# Does the Google Maps javascript library support traffic information?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, client-side

I want to get traffic information on the front-end of my web app. On the back-end this can be easily achieved using the following GET request:
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=...&destinations=...&key=...&travelMode=DRIVING&departure_time=1542600800`

However when using the client-side javascript library for Google Maps and making a request like this:

```
service.getDistanceMatrix({
  origins: '...',
  destinations: '...',
  mode: 'driving',
  unitSystem: window.google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
  avoidHighways: false,
  avoidTolls: false,
  transitOptions: {
    departureTime: new Date('2018-11-18T06:20:00.000'),
  },
}
```

I get the following response where the duration information does not change, no matter what departure time I use.

```
destinationAddresses: ["..."]
originAddresses: ["..."]
    distance: {text: "27.3 km", value: 27256}
    duration: {text: "1 hour 1 min", value: 3689}
```

- It DOES however work for public transport, just not on driving.
- The following article only mentions arrivalTime not departureTime not being supported (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35829984)

So my question is: Am I doing something wrong or is **requesting driving traffic information not available for the JS Google Maps library**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to get the duration in traffic with the client library. My guess is that you nested the departure_time into [transitOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#transit_options) so it will be ignored when using travelMode: driving. From the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_requests):

> transitOptions (optional) — Options that apply only to requests where travelMode is TRANSIT.

Since you are trying to get the response for driving, try the [drivingOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#DrivingOptions) option instead:

```
service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: '...',
    destinations: '...',
    travelMode: 'DRIVING',
    unitSystem: window.google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false,
    drivingOptions: {
        departureTime: new Date()
    }
}
```

The duration field apparently does not include traffic information, the duration_in_traffic object does, which has the following requirements. From the [Google DistanceMatrix Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_responses):

> duration_in_traffic: The length of time it takes to travel this route taking into account current traffic conditions, expressed in seconds (the value field) and as text. The textual value is formatted according to the unitSystem specified in the request (or in metric, if no preference was supplied). The duration_in_traffic is only returned to Google Maps APIs Premium Plan customers where traffic data is available, the mode is set to driving, and departureTime is included as part of the distanceMatrixOptions field in the request.